# React Native, render a button if condition is true

Tags: react-native

I would like to know if there is an easy way to render dynamicly components into a view depending on a condition, like "userpermission='admin', which then shows more buttons that a user has without this var. something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {Button, Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const userpermission = 'admin';
  const adminbutton = '<Button title="Adminstuff"></Button>';

  return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Applikationen</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity 
                style={styles.button}
                onPress={() =>  navigation.navigate('Arbeitszeiterfassung')}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Arbeitszeiterfassung</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            
            // HERE I WANT TO RENDER THE BUTTON
            // if(userpermission == 'admin'){
            //  {adminbutton}
            // }

        </View>
      );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {Button, Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const userpermission = 'admin';

  return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Applikationen</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity 
                style={styles.button}
                onPress={() =>  navigation.navigate('Arbeitszeiterfassung')}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Arbeitszeiterfassung</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            {userpermission == "admin" ? <Button title="Adminstuff" /> : null}

        </View>
      );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const userpermission = 'admin';
  const adminbutton = '<Button title="Adminstuff"></Button>';

  const renderButtonsContainer = () => {
      return <View>
          <Button title="Adminstuff"></Button>
          <Button title="Adminstuff"></Button>
          .........
    </View>

  }

  return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          {userpermission == 'admin' ? renderButtonsContainer() : null }

        </View>
      );
};
```

Comment: Excellent solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A better way to achieve this in functional component.

```js
import { Button } from 'react-native';

const MyButton = ({userpermission}) => {
  if(userpermission == 'admin'){
    return <Button title="Adminstuff"/>
  }
  else {
    return <Button title="Userstuff"/>
  }
}

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const userpermission = 'admin';

  return (
    <View>
        <View>Something</<View>
        <MyButton userpermission={userpermission} />
    </View>
  )
}
```